# jquery in rails doesn't recognize click event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, click, coffeescript

New to using jQuery in Rails and can't get a div to be recognized for click or hover event. Using coffeescript as well, but compile looks fine. The divs all look good in the elements window in Chrome dev tools, but I don't get my console.log in the console window.

portion of my _form.html.haml

```
.field
  = f.label :question
  = f.text_field :question
%p Click the plus sign to add answers.
.field#answerone
  = f.label :answers
  = f.text_field :answers
#plusanswer
  = image_tag("plusWhite.png", :alt => "plus sign")

.actions
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

coffeescript:

```
$("#plusanswer").click ->
  console.log("here we are")
  $("#answerone").clone().appendto()
```

compiled javascript:

```
(function() {

  $("#plusanswer").click(function() {
    console.log("here we are");
    return $("#answerone").clone().appendto();
  });

}).call(this);
```

Is the way I'm doing the image_tag messing things up?

Comment: Are you wrapping the click event in a `$(document).ready()` handler? When I was starting out with CoffeeScript the difference between languages made me forgot to use that as well.

Comment: What is `appendto`? jQuery has `appendTo` but that wants an argument. And you do know that you'll be producing invalid HTML right? You can't have duplicate `id`s in your HTML.

Comment: Sergio, you were right of course. Couldn't give you a click up because you answered in a comment.

Comment: Hey mu, I'm trying to solve the problem you were helping me with the other day about adding fields to a form. Your suggestion was .clone, then .append. I tried chaining them together, then I tried appendTo  (forgot the uppercase T). Now I switched from an id to a class, but nothing is happening.

Comment: @muistooshort -- I tried typing a series of answers separated by commas but get this error: Field was defined as a(n) Array, but received a String with the value "Today, Yesterday, 2 Days Ago".

Comment: [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) needs to be told where to append the thing to. If you clone something with an `id`, you have to change the `id` (or remove it) to avoid duplicate `id`s. The array/string issue sounds like you're missing a `split` somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Sergio is correct in his comment. If your JS comes before the page's markup, then the selector `$(#plusanswer')` runs before that element exists. You can verify this with the code

```
console.log $('#pluganswer').length
```

To fix this, wrap your code in jQuery's document ready wrapper, like so:

```
$ ->
  # the rest of your code goes here
```

This looks a bit magical, but here's how it works: When you pass a function to the jQuery object, `$`, it runs that function only after the `document`'s "ready" event fires. So, again assuming that your code precedes your markup, you should get this behavior:

```
console.log $('#pluganswer').length    # 0
$ ->
  console.log $('#pluganswer').length  # 1, because the page's markup is loaded
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Hey, I got your Coffeescript book. Unfortunately it seems more appropriate for intermediate to advanced Javascript coders. I'm a beginner and stumbled onto Coffeescript just after I started. I went from constant errors due to incorrect ; and } and ) to almost no errors for "punctuation". Now it's all bonehead beginner errors in Javascript . . . and now haml, ruby, etc.

Comment: Well, thanks for buying the book! I do strongly recommend learning the basics of JS before learning CoffeeScript. A great resource is the interactive jQuery Air courses on [CodeSchool](http://www.codeschool.com/).